# Weighted sum of angles modulo $\pi/2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, summation, modular-arithmetic

Angle modulo $\pi /2$ means: $(a+ \pi /2) \mathbin{\%} \pi/2=a$, $a \in [0, \pi/2)$, which could be illustrated as a ‘modulo circle’ in the following figure.

[image]

How to calculate the weighted sum of a set of angles modulo $\pi/2$? I find neither $\sum(w_ia_i)\mathbin{\%}\frac{\pi}{2}$ nor $ \sum w_i(a_i\mathbin{\%}\frac{\pi}{2})$ gives the correct answer.
For instance, $w=\{0.5, 0.5\} (\text{where } \sum w_i=1), a=\{ \frac{\pi}{32}, \frac{15\pi}{32} \} $ (the two angles are marked in red and blue respectively in the figure)
$$\sum(w_ia_i)\mathbin{\%}\frac{\pi}{2}  = \frac{\pi}{4}  $$
$$ \sum w_i(a_i\mathbin{\%}\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{4} $$
While the correct answer seems to be 0 (or $\frac{\pi}{2}$). Intuitively, the two angles are quite close to each other (around 0) in the figure.
Any clues to the tricky $ \sum$ ? I think (the result of) the correct formula should be independent on the order of angels in the set. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no good general notion of weighted sum modulo some number (here, $\frac{\pi}{2}$). To illustrate this problem, consider here the data $a_1 = 0, a_2 = \frac{\pi}{4}$ with respective nonzero weights $w, 1 - w$. The data is symmetric under the horizontal reflection of the circle, and hence any quantity that depends only on that data should be invariant under that reflection. But the only 'angles' (more precisely, points on the circle, identified with elements of $\Bbb R / \frac{\pi}{2} \Bbb Z$) invariant are $0, \frac{\pi}{4}$ themselves, and neither of these can reasonably be called weighted sums of $0, \frac{\pi}{4}$ with nonzero weights.

---

On the other hand, one *can* define a good notion of 'weighted sum' of two angles provided that they do not correspond to antipodal points on the circle (equivalently, that their difference is not equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ modulo $\frac{\pi}{2}$ here): Simply pick a choice of 'angular coordinate' continuous on the minor arc between the two angles (which is defined because points are not antipodal), and declare the weighted sum to be
$$a_1 w_1 + a_2 w_2 \bmod \frac{\pi}{2},$$
where here $a_1$ and $a_2$ denote respectively the coordinates of the two given angles. In the given example, we can choose an 'angular coordinate' with values in $(-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4})$, which is in particular continuous on the minor arc connecting the points on the circle determined by the red and blue arcs. With respect to these coordinates, these points have coordinates $\pm \frac{\pi}{32}$, and so the weighted average of these points with weights $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}$ is simply $0$ (modulo $\frac{\pi}{2}$), yielding the geometrically intuitive answer. One can extend this definition some to sets of more than two angles, again with the requirement that we avoid certain 'indeterminate' data sets.

(It is somewhat inconvenient, incidentally, that we are using reduction modulo $\frac{\pi}{2}$ here, when this particular value plays no special role in this setting---probably it would be easier to see what's going on under the hood here if we worked with the more familiar reduction modulo $1$ or $2 \pi$ instead.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I think the problem is that there is no definition of weighted sum of angles modulo ($\pi/2$).  You give a good example explaining my intuition about two angles near $\pi/2$. 

Yes, actually I have written some codes in JAVA to implement the calculation, $sum(a, b)$, but extending the calculation to more than 2 angles is problematic.

Comment: My strategy is to first calculate $sum(a_1,a_2)=a_{12}$, then calculate $sum(a_{12},a_3)=a_{123}$, $sum(a_{123},a_4)=…$, and so forth. But I find it produces different results when (the order of ) angles are swapped. So far I cannot work out an explicit formula of such $sum(a_1, .., a_n)$ .

Comment: One option is to regard "angles" as unit vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ and then define the weighted average of the vectors $a_i$ with respective weights $w_i$ to be the unit vector
$$\bar{a} := \frac{\sum w_i a_i}{\left\vert\sum w_i a_i\right\vert} ,$$ provided that the sum is nonzero. This has the advantage that it (1) is natural, and (2) extends the definition in the answer.

Comment: The above formula does not work directly, for instance, a={0, $\pi/2$} (corresponding to (0,1) and (1,0)), leads to $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ while the correct should be 0 (or $\pi/2$). Therefore the procedure might be:

First, mapping the angle to vector by $v_i=w_i|cos(4a_i), sin(4a_i)|$

Second, compute $v=\sum v_i $  (vector addition)

Third, mapping back to angle: $a= atan(v)\%\pi/2$

I will try coding to see whether it works.

Comment: Third, mapping back to angle: a=atan(v)/4 (if aran(v) yields a negative angle, plus $2\pi$). My java codes seems working fine.

Comment: On your diagram, $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ both correspond to the same point.